# Opam init - Solver Fail (Debian)

Tags: debian, ocaml, opam

Hy everyone,
I installed opam and when i run:

```
opam init
```

the init fails and give me this error:

```
[ERROR] Solver failed: "/usr/bin/aspcud /tmp/opam-xxx-15/solver-in-15-548b09 /tmp/opam-xxx-15/solver-out-15-8b8a2d
    -count(removed),-sum(request,version-lag),-count(down),-sum(solution,version-lag),-count(changed)" exited with
    code 1 "ERROR: grounder returned with non-zero exit status"
```

how can i Fix it?
The opam version is 2.0.3 and the OS is Debian.
If you need more details just ask me, thank you all.

Comment: There are several Github issues for this that might help: https://github.com/eclipse-fog05/fog05/issues/167 https://github.com/ocaml/opam/issues/3484

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem yesterday: it is related to a Python version inconsistency (3.7 vs 3.6).

I solved it by removing the OPAM debian package and installing OPAM with the install script which is on the github repo:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ocaml/opam/master/shell/install.sh